# postgresql сгруппировать записи по дням по полю с unix timestamp

Tags: postgresql

У меня есть таблица в которой есть поле created с unix timestamp вида (1556517749). Мне нужно сгруппировать записи по дням, как правильно это сделать.

Пытаюсь сделать как-то так(не рабочий пример)

```
SELECT count(*), date(created, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as dt FROM table_name GROUP BY dt;
function date(bigint) does not exist
```

Какой функцией я могу сконвертировать timestamp в дату? Пожалуйста напишите рабочий пример

Comment: Нашел такое решение to_timestamp(created)::date. Насколько корректно его использовать?

Comment: Да, это корректно